# c3p0 and Oracle object type problem

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, c3p0

had several apps with jdbc and Oracle 10g. Now I´m changing the apps for use c3p0. But I have some problems working with Oracle types.

I Have this Oracle type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE DATAOBJ AS OBJECT
(
  ID NUMBER,
  NAME VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

And this Oracle function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_IS_DATA_OBJECT (datar in DATAOBJ) RETURN varchar2 IS
    tmpVar varchar2(150);
    BEGIN
        tmpVar := 'Data object:';
        if datar.id is not null then
            tmpVar := tmpVar || 'id=' || datar.ID;
        end if;

        if datar.name is not null then
            tmpVar := tmpVar || 'name=' || datar.name;
        end if;


    return tmpVar;          

   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       RAISE;
END F_IS_DATA_OBJECT;
```

then I have a app in Java with c3p0 with next classes:
Dataobj.class to represent the object type:

```
    package c3p0pruebas.modelo;

import java.io.Serializable;

import java.sql.SQLData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLInput;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

public class Dataobj implements SQLData, Serializable {

    private String name;
    private Integer id;


    public Dataobj() {
    }

    public String getSQLTypeName() {
        return "DATAOBJ";
    }

    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeInt(id.intValue());
        stream.writeString(name);
    }

    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        id = new Integer(stream.readInt());
        name = stream.readString();
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    ... and its gets and sets ....
```

And the main class and main method:

```
Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection("Mypool"); //I use a class to get connection
     CallableStatement cs = null;
     String error = "";
        try {
/*
//First I made a NativeExtractor of the connection, but the result is the same, I got it from Spring framework.            
//C3P0NativeJdbcExtractor extractor = new C3P0NativeJdbcExtractor();
            //OracleConnection newConnection = (OracleConnection) extractor.getNativeConnection(connection);

            //cs = (OracleCallableStatement) newConnection.prepareCall("{? = call F_IS_DATA_OBJECT(?)}");
*/
            //Creates the object
            Dataobj obj = new Dataobj();
            obj.setId(new Integer(33));
            obj.setName("myName");

            cs = connection.prepareCall("{? = call F_IS_DATA_OBJECT(?)}");

            cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cs.setObject(2, obj);

            cs.execute();
            error = cs.getString(1);

            System.out.println("Result: " + error);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeDBObjects(null,cs,null);
        }
     closeDBObjects(null, null, connection); //Close connection
```

The execution gets:

```
Data object: id=33.
```

I cant get the String (Varchar2) value, the name string.

With oracle arrays of object type, I have the same problem, It worked nice with JDBC. When I worked with Arrays, also, it hasn´t the string values:

```
//Here I use a NativeConnection ...
    Dataobj arrayOfData[] = new Dataobj[myDataObj.size()];
... //Makes the array of DataObj.
                ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("OBJ_ARRAY", newConnection);
            ARRAY arrayDatas = new ARRAY(descriptor, newConnection, arrayOfData);
```

//In this step, objects of arrayDatas haven´t the name string...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It finally works.

Searching, We found out the answer:

We change data definition in the database and now it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE "DATAOBJ" AS OBJECT
(
  vid NUMBER,
  vname NCHAR(50)
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solved without change `VARCHAR2 to NCHAR`, because for me, the `NCHAR` doesn't appear the **String** in the Oracle, stay "?" in all the positions.

I changed the oracle driver of the WAR to the version of my database, in my case was 11.2.0.1.0: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

And i put another driver, that is the NLS for Oracle Objects and Collections:
http://download.oracle.com/otn/utilities_drivers/jdbc/112/orai18n.jar

With this, i solved the problem and the `VARCHAR2` worked fine.

Good luck.